# Codeigniter 4 login form using javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

so basicly the login is working perfectly, I don't have a problem with it, but I am using a brought panel for the application and I want to use the login which came with the panel and it is using javascript.

**Here is the javascript for the modal that appears after submit**

```
        $('#kt_login_signin_submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        validation.validate().then(function(status) {
            if (status == 'Valid') {
                swal.fire({
                    text: "All is cool! Now you submit this form",
                    icon: "success",
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
                    }
                }).then(function() {
                    KTUtil.scrollTop();
                });
            } else {
                swal.fire({
                    text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                    icon: "error",
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                    customClass: {
                        confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-light-primary"
                    }
                }).then(function() {
                    KTUtil.scrollTop();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I can use this piece of javascript to send a request for my login controller once it presses the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

i am new here so bare with me. I dont know how you do your login but to log in with javascript you will need to make an ajax request containing the credentials and also the csrf if you use it. From the snippet I dont see where you make an ajax request just some kind of validation and what to do if it it fails or not.  You need to write the ajax request after your validation passes. Be careful if you have different validation on your server, you will need to regenerate csrf token and pass it back as a response and then you have to update the new value in your form before you resubmit the form again. I dont like this solution but i dont know how to do it other wat. I haven’t work with ajax just vania javascript. You can see how to construct a simple jquery ajax request. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: I realized that I had to request it through ajax so I can get the data to my controller. I will do it later when I get home and them come back with an anwer on how it goes.

Comment: It seems by answer helped you. I am glad. Please dont forget to rate it.